# If $f_n$ converges to $f$ over an interval $I$ then it also converges over $I\setminus \{p\}$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, sequence-of-function

I was given the following question as part of my Calculus 2 assignment:
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions that converge to $f$, but doesn't converge uniformly, over an interval $I$. Given $p\in I$ show that $f_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} f$ (not uniformly) over the interval $I\setminus\{p\}$.

Here is what I started writing:
We know that $f_n\longrightarrow f$ but not uniformly, therefore there exists $L>0$ such that $\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\longrightarrow L$. We'll denote the supremum with the sequence $\{a_n\}$ meaning $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f_n(a_n)-f(a_n)|$.

I have no idea really how to articulate what I want to say. Intuitively I know that, for an infinite set of cardinality $\aleph$, removing a finite number of elements does not change the supremum of the set. I am just having a problem explaining that rigorously and I would like a hint or a guide in the right direction on how to write that thought.

Comment: Your " therefore there exists L>0 such that [etc.]" is wrong. The supremum is off topic here since there is no uniform convergence. " for an infinite set of cardinality ℵ, removing a finite number of elements does not change the supremum" is also wrong.

Comment: What you should do first is make precise what you mean here by "$f_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} f$ (not uniformly) over $E$" (for any set $E$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thinking about it now I can see why saying that "there exists $L>0$..." is not correct as the limit might not even exist. But when can removing a finite number of elements from an infinite set of cardinality $aleph$ change the supremum?
Regarding writing the definition of $f_n\longrightarrow f$. I tried that but I also came empty handed. I'll keep trying though.

Comment: @RamiHashan $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$

Comment: @Zackkenyon Oh, I guess that slipped my mind as I was strictly thinking of continuous intervals, but the question does not state $I$ is continuous.